# Конструктор по умолчанию для массива структур в структуре

Tags: c++, конструктор

Всем привет. Вопрос такой, есть 2 структуры. Как правильно объявить конструктор по умолчанию в структуре One? Интересует конкретно в случае массива структуры point из 50-ти элеметов? что бы он инициализировался по умолчанию значениями конструктора Reach для всех 50-ти элементов

```
#include ".\Point.h"

struct Reach
{
unsigned short az; 

Point location;           

float block;    

Reach(unsigned short _az = 0,
           Point _point = Point(),
           float _block = 0.0f)
    : az(_az)
    , location(_location)
    , block(_block)
{}
};

struct One
{
unsigned short number;  

Reach point[50];  // Точки 

bool isMin;                     

One(unsigned short _number = 0,
           bool _isMin = false)
    : number(_number)
    , point()
    , isMin(_isMin)
{}
};
```

Comment: По-моему, вы это уже сделали, нет? http://ideone.com/JAJ8xs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экземпляры класса `Reach` в массиве `Reach point[50]` и так у вас будут инициализироваться конструктором по умолчанию класса `Reach`. Т.е. тем самым конструктором, который вы написали с теми самыми параметрами по умолчанию.

Для этого можно было вообще не упоминать `point` в списке инициализации конструктора `One`. Язык и так гарантирует вызов конструкторов по умолчанию для элементов вашего массива. Но явное упоминание в виде `point()`, как у вас сейчас, тоже даст тот же самый эффект.

Comment: Спасибо. Я не был до конца уверен, что это правильный подход.